# Можно ли изменить payload на самом сайте vk?

Tags: вконтакте

Есть кнопка под сообщением в vk, могу ли я изменить payload этой кнопки через DevTools в браузере или что-то еще?

Comment: какая кнопка под сообщение в вк?

Comment: callback скорее всего